# why mouse cursor and red line not same position when add zoom 0.5 in to body tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

why mouse cursor and red line not same position when add zoom 0.5 in to body tag ?

When use on `zoom 1;` it's work good,

How can i do work on `zoom 0.5` (except zoom 1;) ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ksfqgv0p/6/

```
var isResizing = false;
$(function () {
   var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');

    container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
    });

    container.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
        return;
        left.css('width', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
        handle.css('margin-left', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `e.clientX` returns mouse position on screen not on your object, so then this value is applied to `width` attribute it is 2x smaller than it must be, so you need to divide this value by zoom level to get correct mouse position on that zoomed out object.

Like this:

```
left.css('width', ((e.clientX/$('body').css('zoom')) - container.offset().left));
handle.css('margin-left', ((e.clientX/$('body').css('zoom')) - container.offset().left));
```

Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksfqgv0p/8/)

```js
var isResizing = false;
$(function () {
   var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');

    container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
    });

    container.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
        return;
        console.log(container.offset().left);
        console.log(e.clientX);
        left.css('width', ((e.clientX/$('body').css('zoom')) - container.offset().left));
        handle.css('margin-left', ((e.clientX/$('body').css('zoom')) - container.offset().left));
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    /* Disable selection so it doesn't get annoying when dragging. */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: moz-none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
#container #left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 750px;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.pilsnertop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Dog-Header3.jpg");
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 9;
}
#container #right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://www.twitrcovers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Dog-Butterfly-l.jpg");
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#container #handle {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 742px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 8px;
    cursor: w-resize;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    zoom:0.5;
"
>


<div id="container">
    <!-- Left side -->
    <div id="left"> 
        <!-- Actual resize handle -->
        <div id="handle"></div> This is the right side's content!
This is the left side's content! </div>
    <!-- Right side -->
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>




</body>
```